# oracle sql. transform one column into one row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need an sql select statement that would transform

```
1
2
3
4
```

into `1 2 3 4`

Without using PIVOT functions as I am running oracle 10 database. 
Searched quite a lot on the Internet but surprisingly found nothing.

Little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `pivot` almost as efficiently using a cross join:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then t.col end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then t.col end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then t.col end) as col3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then t.col end) as col4
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by NULL) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know a solution for the same problem if the number of columns is not limited to 4? Because in my problem - there are 6 of them and i imagine that I could have come across even higher number of columns

Comment: @Dennis . . . A SQL select query has to have a fixed number columns.  You can add additional clauses in the `select` for addition columns.  But you cannot vary the number (they will be populated with `NULL` if there is no value).  Alternatively, you could use `list_agg` to put them all in one column, with delimiters.

Comment: Right, I see. Thanks a lot. I'll jot this solution down, as it seems to be a trivial task.

Comment: Either Im doing something wrong or this query returns the row filled with only max values from the column